# Is there a way to move YouTube app from TV and Video on PS4?

Tags: ps4

When I want to start YouTube app on my PS4 I have to open "TV and Video" first and it takes some time to load all the ads, and YouTube app is always in the end of app list.

Is there any way to move YouTube (and other video streaming apps) to my home screen?

I've found some old threads on this topic which say 'No', I hope things have changed in 2018.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to add apps and games directly to your home screen, however, you can create folders which appear on your home screen and add all of your favorite apps inside.

Comment: This doesn't work! I can do it for games, but for YouTube there is no such option.

Comment: Apps are listed in the add-to folder list but are all greyed out preventing them from being added.