# Can I rearrange or remove apps from the shortcut at the top of the TV and Video app?

Tags: ps4

The TV and Video app on my PS4 has a short bar at the top of some “favorite” streaming video services. All the hits are there like Netflix, Amazon, Hulu and HBO Now...

Except, for example, I’m an HBO Go subscriber, not HBO Now. I have the correct app installed, but there seems to be no way for me to remove the icon for the one I don’t want. Not only that, but I also can’t rearrange the TV and video apps that are installed to move the ones I use, like HBO Go, to the front of the line.

Is there some way to rearrange this menu or to remove items from it?

Comment: I could have sworn this was asked before... though I'm probably thinking about something else. But yeah, this is a super annoying feature (or lack of). It would annoy me to no end if Sony decided that I shouldn't need the Netflix or YouTube apps in that top menu anymore in favor of other apps...

Comment: @BrootsWaymb You might be thinking about [Is there a way to move YouTube app from TV and Video on PS4?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/336535/is-there-a-way-to-move-youtube-app-from-tv-and-video-on-ps4). But yes, the lack of this feature is incredibility annoying

Comment: @Wondercricket - yeah, that one looks familiar. A different, but equally annoying lack of feature.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm late, but I know the answer to this one.

The short answer, no. You can't. But honestly, it doesn't make much of a difference because even if there was a way to remove them, they would still take up space since they have to keep the option of restoring them.

Comment: It's not a matter of space, it's a matter of convenience. There are apps there that I will never use, and yet I have to scroll past them every time, to get to the apps that I actually use. I don't subscribe to Disney+ but it's always selected by default.